# Find all differentiable functions $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for which $g'$ is continuous such that $g'(x)\geq (g(x))^2$ for every $x$

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Find all differentiable functions $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for which $g'$ is continuous such that $g'(x)\geq (g(x))^2$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

**My work:**

The only function $g$ that I was able to find is $g=0_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Firstly, it is obvious that $(g(x))^2\geq0$, so $g'(x)\geq0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore, $g$ is an increasing function.

My best try for this problem was to try to choose $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $m \in \mathbb{R_+}$ such that I will somehow be able to apply the fact that $g'(c)=\frac{g(x+m)-g(x)}{m}$, for some $c\in(x,x+m)$ by Lagrange's theorem. From here it follows that $\frac{g(x+m)-g(x)}{m} \geq g(c)^2$

From here I got completely stuck, and I don't know how to continue. Intuitively, I feel like if $g$ is not the zero function, then somehow, $(g(x))^2$ will increase too fast at some point for $g'(x)$ to keep being bigger than it.

Comment: Assume $g(0)\neq 0$. Then we can find a lower bound for $g$ on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ with $g(x)-g(0)=\int_0^xg'(t)\,dt = \int_0^xg(t)^2\,dt$.

Comment: One thing you know is that, on an interval $[a,b]$ where $g$ is nonzero, $\int_a^x\,(g(\xi))^{-2} g’(\xi)\,d\xi \geq x-a$. Evaluate the integral.

Comment: @Aruralreader Thank you! I think I got it now. I was just unable to understand how to tie together $g'(x)$ and $(g(x))^2$, but your idea is brilliant.

Comment: You can also observe that if there exists $a$ such that $g(x)>0$ for $x>a$, then you must have $$\left(\frac1{g(x)}\right)'\leq -1$$for $x>a$. So that $h(x) = \frac1{g(x)}$ should be strictly positive with derivative $h'(x) \leq -1$, for $x > a$, a contradiction. You can work similarly at the other side.

Comment: @dfnu Nice idea! The other side can be performed by considering $f(x)=-g(-x).$

Answer (score 1):

I expand a little bit on my comment.

Recall that $g(x)$ is non decreasing. Suppose there exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $g(x) > 0$ for $x > a$. Therefore, for $x>a$, we can rewrite OP's inequality as $$\frac{g'(x)}{g^2(x)}\geq 1,$$ that is
$$\left(\frac1{g(x)}\right)' \leq -1.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
If we let $h(x) = \frac1{g(x)}$, the above condition implies that, for $x>a$, $h(x)>0$, and $h'(x) \leq -1$. This is clearly a contradiction. In fact if $\alpha > a$ and $\beta > h(\alpha)$, then we have
$$\frac{h(\beta + \alpha)-h(\alpha)}{\beta}> -\frac{h(\alpha)}{\beta}>-1,$$and MVT guarantees the existence of $\gamma \in (\alpha, \alpha +\beta)$ such that $$h'(\gamma) = \frac{h(\beta + \alpha)-h(\alpha)}{\beta}>-1.$$

Therefore we must have $g(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$.

Suppose now that there exists $b\in \mathbb R$ such that $g(x) < 0$ for $x<b$. We can use again \eqref{1} to observe that $h(x) = \frac1{g(x)}$ must satisfy the conditions $h(x) < 0$ and $h'(x) \leq -1$ for all $x < b$, again a contradiction (proceed as above).

Thus it must be $g(x) \equiv 0$.